# Add AcceptType to Mock of HttpRequestBase

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, moq

Simple question here. I am trying to mock the HttpRequestBase and add two AcceptTypes.

I thought this was the approach but it wasn't and Googling / digging around has not revealed anything to me.

```
var request = new Mock<HttpRequestBase>();
   request.Setup(p => p.HttpMethod).Returns("POST");
   request.Setup(a => a.Headers.Add("AcceptType", "ABC"));
   request.Setup(z => z.Headers.Add("AcceptType", "QWE"));
```

### EDIT

According to the answer by [dee](https://stackoverflow.com/users/863240/dee) I understood how I misunderstood the Mock setup / Returns combination.

So my final answer is as seen below but it came about completely by the answer given.

```
new string[] fakeHeaders = new string[]
{ "ABC","QWE" };

Mock<HttpRequestBase> requestBaseMock = new Mock<HttpRequestBase>();
requestBaseMock.Setup(r => r.HttpMethod).Returns("POST");
requestBaseMock.Setup(r => r.Headers).Returns(fakeHeaders);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tryied to create the *fake headers collection* first and then return it from `Setup` of `Headers`?

```
NameValueCollection fakeHeaders = new NameValueCollection();
fakeHeaders.Add("AcceptType", "ABC");
fakeHeaders.Add("AcceptType", "QWE");

Mock<HttpRequestBase> requestBaseMock = new Mock<HttpRequestBase>();
requestBaseMock.Setup(r => r.HttpMethod).Returns("POST");
requestBaseMock.Setup(r => r.Headers).Returns(fakeHeaders);
```